# What undergraduate work stays on a CV once you start graduate school?

Tags: cv, undergraduate

I'm about to graduate with my BS and I'm trying to decide whether it's worth it to submit a paper for publication in an undergraduate journal, given that I've already applied to and picked a PhD program and I start on the fall.

What sorts of papers, presentations, and awards that I received as an undergrad are still worth mentioning on a CV even after I graduate? Do my accomplishments restart like they did after graduating high school?

Comment: I would say: keep all publications (in your field) in your CV, even if published when you were 7 years old.  Non-published work, however, should probably be omitted.

Comment: I would keep awards on there too, especially if they are prestigious (university/ national level) or came with a monetary prize. Probably best to omit things like your knitting club's award for most stripey scarf (unless you're doing a PhD in knitting!).

Comment: Dumb question to those about to answer: How much does your answer depend on what OP intends for the CV?

Comment: @JackBauer - (a) I don't understand your question; (b) whenever your preface with "dumb question" I get confused and start wondering if you're being sarcastic.  My suggestion would be to just ask whatever's on your mind.

Comment: @aparente001 I was thinking the answer would be "Depends what you're using the CV for". But then how much does it depend>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I learned was to leave off everything from undergrad except your degree in the education section. You can also include you major(s) and minor(s), and if you graduated with any honors in that section.

That said, I learned this as a graduate student applying for faculty jobs. I would say that you can probably leave your undergrad achievements on you CV during the first few years of your graduate program, but as you advance further in your career, I would eventually remove the undergraduate items.

Regarding your paper: 
If you're interested in a career in academia, my advice is this: if the quality of your paper is exceptional, and/or there's room to further develop it to merit submission to a professional journal, I would try doing that instead, otherwise set it aside for the time being and focus your energy elsewhere. In academia, publications in student journals typically don't weigh much, unless it's an especially reputable one. I can't speak for expectations in other industries - a publication in an undergrad journal might weigh more for non-academic jobs.

Best of luck with your PhD program!

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering writing and publishing something in an undergraduate publication -- don't do it for the sheen it might add to your CV.  If you do it, do it because you find the subject matter interesting and you think you can write an article others would enjoy reading.

Note, the more you write, the better you get at writing.

(Separately, after publication, you could ask for guidance about what to include and what to exclude from your CV, if the existing Q&As here have left this an open question.)

Comment: To clarify, I've already written the paper. I'm not sure I want to go through the effort of submitting it.

Comment: @DarylBagley - Is it that onerous, actually?  Can you give me an idea how much time would be involved?  I could sort of see one feeling "Mph, why bother rewriting this thing according to the editor's feedback," but if it's just a matter of submitting -- I don't really understand why you're hesitating.

Answer (score 1):

Really just degree, institution, and GPA.  I would add varsity athlete if you did that (companies love that ess...not saying it is right...but they do.)  But president of the feeding hobos club, internships, best chemistry student...nobody cares after grad school.

But that ug GPA will stay with you forever.  I am 50 and it is still noticed.